# d3: Multi-Series Line Chart with associative array

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I am trying to create a d3 multi-series chart with an array of arrays, rather than an object. But I am facing issues and not sure how to make it work.

Basically the default data is in this format:-

```
var data = [
    {date:"1-May-12","New York":"58.13", "San Francisco":"58.13", "Austin": "43"},
    {date:"30-Apr-12","New York":"53.98" , "San Francisco":"48.13", "Austin": "53"},
    {date:"27-Apr-12","New York":"67.00", "San Francisco":"38.13", "Austin": "63"},
    {date:"26-Apr-12","New York":"89.70", "San Francisco":"28.13", "Austin": "73"},
    {date:"25-Apr-12","New York":"99.00", "San Francisco":"18.13", "Austin": "83"}
];
```

I want to use:-

```
var data = [
  ["date", "New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"],
  ["1-May-12", "43.98", "48.13", "43"],
  ["30-Apr-12", "53.98", "88.13", "53"],
  ["27-Apr-12", "63", "68", "63"],
  ["26-Apr-12", "73", "58", "73"],
  ["25-Apr-12", "83", "48", "83"]
]
```

Please see plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/E0H45we6GKtXZcHMhbay?p=preview

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly I think I could summarise it by saying that you have the data in a JSON format, but you want to use it in a csv format.

If this is correct, you *could* approach the problem in a slightly different way and have your data file external to the main script and then when you read the data in you could use `d3.json` or `d3.csv` depending on the format. The example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8603837) uses an external csv file.

EDIT: Here is an example on bl.ocks.org using your code and an external csv file
http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/d5ecdbefb7cc43a48f59

Comment: Sorry, for not being clear. Actually, I would get data from an API as JSON format and I can not change the format. Hence I have hard coded the data within the script for the example.
Your example works fine with external csv file, but not as embedded data.